# Why Islam is considered as a religion of terrorists?

Tags: quran

I just want to know why this religion is hated all around the world and is considered as a religion of terrorists?

Comment: Do you know the most fast spreading religion of world today is Islam? Why would sane and wise people become terrorists then(according to you)?

Comment: People who are ignorant about Islam are the ones who consider it as a religion of terrorists.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know how to answer this question! Its answer could take me 24 days writing it and 10 days of yours reading that answer! But to summarize I would write the below answer:

**Islam Itself teaches Peace:**

Islam never orders any of its followers to become a terrorist.The Holy Scripture teaches us to be peaceful even to plants as it orders us that when you overcome your enemy then don't even destroy their plants and trees and be kind. As it is stated in [this verse of Quran.](http://corpus.quran.com/translation.jsp?chapter=5&verse=32)

> Sahih International: Because of that, We decreed upon the Children of Israel that whoever kills a soul unless for a soul or for corruption [done] in the land – it is as if he had slain mankind entirely. And whoever saves one – it is as if he had saved mankind entirely. And our messengers had certainly come to them with clear proofs. Then indeed many of them, [even] after that, throughout the land, were transgressors.

This order is universal for all Muslims. And in [this Verse](http://quran.com/6/151) it is clearly prohibited to kill any soul:

> Say, "Come, I will recite what your Lord has prohibited to you. [He commands] that you not associate anything with Him, and to parents, good treatment, and do not kill your children out of poverty; We will provide for you and them. And do not approach immoralities - what is apparent of them and what is concealed. And do not kill the soul which Allah has forbidden [to be killed] except by [legal] right. This has He instructed you that you may use reason."

So it is clear that Islam teaches peace.

**Then Why Islam is termed as Religion of terrorists?**

The answer of this can be a short one and that is "*Because of present day politics of some governments.*" I mean that you know Muslims have been termed as terrorists since world trade centre attack.The 9/11 attack is still a mystery that who did it but America said that Muslims did.

Though I don't think a sound mind would accept it. But one would say "Why were Muslims blamed? Why not Jews or Christians or Hindus?" And the answer is that "Because America wanted to attack Afghanistan and Muslims dwell in Afghanistan. Because America wanted to take the oil wells of Iraq and Muslims dwell in Iraq."

Don't misunderstand me.Do you know that Osama was ally of America against Russia war and America provided them with arms and ammunitions and Osama was widely interviewed by American journalists of that time and he was termed as Hero? But now, the same America calls the same Osama a terrorist!

I admit that there are some evils in Muslims which are given names of different terrorist groups and they are terrorists but that doesn't change the reality that Islam is religion of Peace.Some chemicals are poisons but all chemicals aren't! Some tomatoes are rotten but all tomatoes can't be thrown away saying that they are tomatoes and the tomatoes over there were rotten!

If some one calls Islam a religion of terrorists due to "9/11,ISIS,Al-Qaeda etc." then he must call Christianity a religion of terrorists due to [this list](http://aattp.org/here-are-8-christian-terrorist-organizations-that-equal-isis/) and [this list](http://www.patheos.com/blogs/danthropology/2015/04/christian-terrorist-groups-exist-and-we-often-simply-ignore-them/) and [this wikipedia article.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christian_terrorism) And what would you say about [Irgun group of Jews](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irgun)?

Every religion has got some terrorist groups out of its followers but they aren't ordered by their religion to become terrorists so none of the religions is a religion of terrorists. Rather I always use to say that all terrorists follow one religion and the name of that religion is "Terrorism" and its teachings are just one sentence "Spread Terror, Be leader!"

I acknowledge many of you will not agree with what I think so please be critic and let me know what are your thoughts!